# Rolle's Theorem: $f(x)=3-\left\lvert x-3 \right\rvert$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Determine whether Rolle's Theorem can be applied to the function on the closed interval of $[a,b]$.  If Rolle's Theorem can be applied, find all values of c in the open interval $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. If Rolle's Theorem can not be applied explain why.
>
> $f(x)=3-\left\lvert x-3 \right\rvert$ in the interval of $[0,6]$

I began the problem by finding the derivative, and looking for the critical numbers and got that the critical number was at $x=3$.  I also saw that the function was not differentiable in the interval of $[0,6]$ How would I word my answer, would I state that the function is not differentiable in the open interval of $(0,6)$ leading to Rolle's Theorem not be applicable in this certain scenario?

Comment: Well, if the function is not diff at$x=3$, then certainly the function is not a diff function in the interval $(0,6)$. So you are really "there"...

Comment: Your explanation is totally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>3 \;\;$

$f(x)=6-x \implies f'(3^+)=-1$

for $x<3 $

$\;\;f(x)=x \implies f'(3^-)=1$

thus $f$ is not differentiable at $x=3$ , and consequently not differentiable at $(0,6)$ since it contains $3$.

thus we cannot apply Rolle's Theorem in the interval $(0,6)$.